# Montar um player de imagem e vídeo em delphi

Tags: delphi

tenho um projeto pra faculdade e não sei como posso resolver isso.

A ideia é fazer um player de vídeo e imagem juntos, fazer com que eu possa colocar as imagens e vídeos na mesma playlist e cada item só pode rodar 15 segundos.

Eu tenho um player de vídeo e imagem pronto já, só que não consigo mesclar os dois para me atender. Segue links dos dois projetos:
https://goo.gl/RyCmgZ

Answer (score 1):

@Renato_Souza_Delphi, explicando de maneira bem simples o que eu tinha mencionado na outra resposta.

No Delphi na barra de menu vá em:

1. *Component* / *Import* / *Component*.
2. Na tela seguinte escolha a opção *Import ActiveX Control*.
3. na proxima tela localize no *grid*: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
4. Selecione o nome da paleta como deseja eu deixei como `ActiveX`.
5. Na próxima tela escolha a opção *Install To New Package* e finalize.
6. Depois verifique que foi criada no Delphi a paleta de componentes que você definiu anteriormente ( passo 4 ).
7. Coloque no *Form* o componente `TWindowsMediaPlayer` desta nova paleta e um `Timer` configurando-o com o tempo que você quiser.
8. Vá na propriedade do `TWindowsMediaPlayer` e ajuste sua propriedade `Align`: `alClient`.
9. Segue o código abaixo com uma simples implementação, na linha de código contendo `FLista.Add('arquivo.png')` substitua a *string* contendo o caminho dos arquivos que        você quer apresentar.

### Implementação

```pascal
unit frmPrincipal;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.OleCtrls, WMPLib_TLB, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    wm: TWindowsMediaPlayer;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FIndex: Integer;
    FLista: TStringList;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FLista :=  TStringList.Create;
  FIndex := 0;
  FLista.Add('arquivo.png');
  Flista.Add('arquivo.mp3');
  Timer1.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FreeAndNil( FLista );
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FIndex > 1 then
    Exit;
  wm.URL := FLista.Strings[FIndex];
  wm.controls.play;
  Inc(FIndex);
end;

end.
```

Isso é um exemplo simples do que você pode fazer facilmente com o `Activex` do windows media player, existem inúmeros métodos e recursos que você pode implementar qualquer dúvida é só falar, não pude detalhar e escrever um código consistente por falta de tempo mas espero que você tenha pegado a ideia.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o ActiveX control do windows media player que resolve o seu problema já que ele pode rodar videos e abrir JPEG. Importe o ocx que fica na pasta system32 e adapte o controle para suas necessidades.

Comment: @Renato_Souza_Delphi, vou postar o código no final de semana.